# rosjava listener(pub/sub example) error

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to Listening the Hello message by rosjava(pure java) client.
The error is occured, when received a message from publisher.
I ran roscore(not in rosjava) and I sent the message by rostopic pub /chatter std_msgs/String -1 "Hello".

```
    Jun 22, 2011 5:00:10 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "Hello"
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.ros.Publisher.publish(Lorg/ros/message/Message;)V
    at org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger.publishToRosout(RosoutLogger.java:64)
    at org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger.info(RosoutLogger.java:139)
    at org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.Listener$1.onNewMessage(Listener.java:45)
    at org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.Listener$1.onNewMessage(Listener.java:42)
    at org.ros.internal.node.topic.Subscriber$MessageReadingThread.run(Subscriber.java:85)
```

client source is as below.

```
import org.ros.NodeConfiguration;
import org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.*;

public class ROS_Listener {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello - Listener");
        
        org.ros.NodeConfiguration node_cfg = org.ros.NodeConfiguration.createDefault();
        org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.Listener ros_listener = new org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.Listener();
        ros_listener.main(node_cfg);
      }
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10353/rosjava-listener(pub/sub-example)-error/) by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-06-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on 2011-06-23**:
Thanks for answer. I cleaned this project. but, It has same error.

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2011-06-22**:
That's a pretty strange error. Maybe you should try doing a clean compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried this myself at the latest revision by doing the following (which worked for me). Please pull the latest version of rosjava and try to get it working like this:

roscd rosjava
rosmake
ant dist
roscore
rosrun rosjava run org.ros.tutorials.pubsub.Listener
rostopic pub /chatter std_msgs/String -1 "Hello"

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2011-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on 2011-06-28**:
Yes, I have pulled latest revision. It is working well. than you.